# LUKS password stopped working

Tags: luks

I have an old Macbook pro that I installed Debian 10 on and encrypted it. Don't have the Luks Header file/backup. Suddenly, the password used to access it stopped working. I know that I am using the right password because I know and have saved its hashsum, so it is 100% correct. I'm using the correct keyboard layout too.

I didn't do any updates or installs or anything at all to the device. My question is, if I am not able to decrypt it (tried that via the fallback tty as well as a live arch image), does that 100% mean that the header has been corrupted?

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383788/luks-passphrase-doesnt-work) answer, they mention that plaintext string between the 0x1000 and 0x20400 sectors mean that the header is corrupted. Is this true? In my hexdump, the output between sectors **0x1000** and **0x20400** **DO** have plaintext strings and zeroed out rows. But they mostly seem to be LUKS-related text (e.g. I'm seeing `{"type": "luks2"||, "key_size": 64...........`). And the zeroed out rows occur at 0x000012e0 after the string `"keyslot_size": "16744448"`}}. There are some other zeroed out rows before 0x20400.

Is this a corrupted header? Running the repair function outputs "No known problems detected for LUKS header".

Comment: The linked answer is a few years old and still talking about LUKS 1, you are using LUKS 2 so it's different. You can check cryptsetup luksDump for key material offset and length - that is where you find your random data in a LUKS 2 setup. (This kind of check is very superficial. It's also possible to corrupt in a way that can't be seen in a hexdump. Since there is no checksum for key material there is no way to know for sure.)